# ¿Existe alguna estrategia para llevar el control de versiones y la trazabilidad de los cambios?

Tags: genexus, dll

Somos un equipo de 8+ desarrolladores que simultáneamente modificamos los objetos de la misma base de conocimientos de forma paralela y exportamos los cambios a un consolidador central que se encarga de compilar los cambios y distribuirlos a los clientes. En un mes pueden llegar a ser hasta 20 cambios del modelo.

En la actualidad tenemos un sistema donde se registran los requerimientos y los objetos que se van modificando y nos vemos en la necesidad de llevar un control de versiones más riguroso y de poder establecer la trazabilidad de las compilaciones que se encuentran en producción.

Quiero pensar en algo así como un sistema forense que me permita detectar en las DLL's instaladas quién modificó el objeto genexus que le dio origen y cuándo se modificó.

¿Alguien ha implementado una solución parecida o tiene alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Un sistema de control de versiones también puede controlar las versiones de los binarios (sólo que resolver conflictos no va a ser igual que en archivos planos). Los commits van a decir el historial de modificaciones en un archivo dll. Sería sano hacer versiones del código que genera esos dll

Answer (score 1):

Una excelente herramienta para esto es [Genexus Server.](https://gxserver.com/en/main)

Answer (score 0):

Si no quieres el Genexus Server, puedes intentar dejar la kb en un PC servidor, y desde las otras maquinas conectarse con el `knowledgebase.connection` redireccionando al pc server y teniendo los mdf de la kb en cada equipo developer

tiene su parametrización pero es totalmente funcional para trabajar en equipo